# Get facebook profile picture URL

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I just logged a user into my app using the facebook SDK, how can I get the url to their profile picture? So far I have:

```
    func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser) {
      activityIndicator.startAnimating()
      println("User: \(user)")
      println("User ID: \(user.objectID)")
      println("User Name: \(user.name)")
      var userEmail = user.objectForKey("email") as String
      println("User Email: \(userEmail)")
}
```

I tried `println( user.objectForKey("picture") as String)` but that doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the URL yourself as long as you have the users Facebook ID. Using `user.objectID` from your code:

```
let avatarLocation = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(user.objectID)/picture"
```

That will give you a small variant of the users avatar. You can also specify a size, and they'll try and match the size you request.

```
let avatarLocation = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(user.objectID)/picture?width=640&height=640"
```

Both Strings above. They'll need to be used to create a NSURL if you actually want to retrieve them.